# WebClient can't download string from website API path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, discord, basic

I'm trying to make a program, that checks if a discord nitro classic gift link is working, and I found the path to where it shows "invalid code" or "working code", but when I use "webClient.downloadstring(request)" it says it is unable to do so.
This is my code

```
Dim request As String = String.Format("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/38avVXeqpvHSJ9X3/")
Dim webClient As New Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(request)
```

The "38avVXeqpvHSJ9X3" in the link is just a random invalid gift link I've used. The DownloadString works on other sites and on discord front page as well, but not on this path, any ideas to work around this?

EDIT:
I've tried adding a header, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
 Using client As New WebClient
        client.Headers("User-Agent") = "Mozilla/4.0"

        Dim arr As String = String.Format("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/38avVXeqpvHSJ9X3/")
        Dim res As String = client.DownloadString(arr)
```

Comment: Put some headers into the request, it probably expects things like a User Agent.

Comment: I saw a lot of solves on other threads saying that, but I've tried something a like, but it doesn't work. I'll update my post and include the new code I've tried.